# JAX WS services wsdlLocation

Tags: jax-ws

Could somebody explain to me why I need use `wsdlLocation` file in

```
javax.xml.ws.Service service =
    javax.xml.ws.Service.create(`wsdlLocation`, javax.xml.namespace.QName)

MCIDispositionRights port = service.getPort(MCIDispositionRights.class);
```

I dont want use the `wsdlLocation` file;  I need to use just URL.

Does somebody know which information is parsed from wsdl file for client.
Why do I need the wsdl in the client part?  I could not find any information about it.

Answer (score -1):

> In Short:

If you don't give wsdl, how will client know which service to call, which operation to call and what is the structure of operation?

Once you provide the wsdl information, entire schema/structure is re-created for you including transport information, security information (e.g if invocation of service requires WS-Policy information.

And wsdl is for "client" only.If there was no use of it for client, why would anyone publish this interface document.

Thanks

> In detail:

Go through wsdl document to understand the usage of different elements.

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/web_services/ws_wsdlstructure.html